# What is the reason to big overhead while send data using spidev

Tags: embedded-linux, spi

I'm using spidev driver (linux embedded) to send data through spi communication.

I sent 7 bytes of data (in 1 Mb clock rate using "write" command) and I noticed that it takes me approximately 200 microseconds to complete that operation (I used scope to verify that the clock rate is correct). 
Time of sending that data should be 56 microseconds + some overhead but it seems to me too much.

What can be the reason for that overhead?

Is it connected to the switch between user space and kernel space? or is it connected to spidev implementation?

Comment: Try to measure the time taken to send different frame lengths as well, such as 14, 28 and larger and then do a simple linear equation to understand the impact of the kernel call versus the driver.

Comment: I measured the time and this is my reasults: 7 bytes- 167 microsec, 14 - 258, 28- 469, 100 - 1395. Any idea?